# How to find in file line that contains string and add something at the end of that line

Tags: php, find

I have file to edit that contains:

```
Categories,
Diamond,10,11,
Coal,21,21,
```

**How to add string at the end of line containing "Diamond"?**

What I have is code that can add string at the end of a file but don't know how to make it to add that string in specyfic line:

```
$function_Result = mysql_fetch_row($function_Ask, 0);

$file_To_Edit = "item_Data.csv";
$opened_File = fopen($file_To_Edit, 'w') or die("Error. Code:2 - Can not open file $file_To_Edit");

$string_Data = $function_Result[0] . ",";
fwrite($opened_File, $string_Data);
fclose($opened_File);
```

Comment: Its a string that I will be adding: `$function_Result = mysql_fetch_row($function_Ask, 0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have used an `preg_replace` if the file content isn't too large.

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt');
/* in case of unwanted \r */ $content = str_replace("\r", '', $content);
$content = preg_replace("#^(Diamond.*)$#m", '$1' . $append, $content);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```

Comment: +1 Sods, it didn't occur to me to use regex. Your solution is way nicer than mine

Comment: The file will be big, containing 80 lines of very long strings (VERY LONG)

Comment: If it's not several megabytes this will still be quick

Comment: What is this `$1` and `$append`?

Comment: `'$1'` is the regex match (being the line containing 'Diamond') and `$append` is the data you would like to add to that line

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content() in localhost\index.php: `$content_Adder = file_get_content('item_data.csv');
`

Comment: It's `file_get_contents` with an **s**

Comment: sorry, easy to forget to write the funtion as plural

Comment: in ``$content_Adder = preg_replace("#^(Diamond.*)$#", '$1' . $function_Result, $content_Adder);`` $function_Result is an array, you forgot `[0]`

Comment: and you may want to replace Diamond with $item_Name

Comment: are you sure it `$content_Adder = preg_replace("#^($item_Name.*)$#", '$1' . $function_Result, $content_Adder);
  file_put_contents('item_data.csv', $content_Adder);
 }` inputs strings correctly?

Comment: sorry, forgot the PCRE_MULTILINE, there should be a m after the 2nd #, se edited answer

Comment: @Puggan Se :))) It overides my `Categories,
Diamond,10,11,
Coal,21,21,` width: `Categories,
357
Coal,21,21,` - thats not welcome

Comment: sounds like a "\r" got in you way, `$content = str_replace("\r", "", $content);`

Comment: Can you refer to existing example?

Comment: `echo "apa123\r456"` going to end up at a console as "456123", as \r returns the marker to a, and writes 456 above apa

Comment: I dont get it Puggan Se, how to use it in my case?

Answer (score 3):

all the previous posted solutions may fail when working on big files. here is one which works on files of any size. (should add some checks if files are readable and writeable etc.)

```
<?php
$file = "item_Data.csv"
$tmpFile = $file .".tmp";

$in = fopen($file, "r")
$out = fopen($tmpFile, "w")

while (($buffer = fgets($in)) !== false) {

    if (preg_match('/my search pattern/', $buffer )) {

        $buffer .= 'append this to the matched line';
    }

    fwrite($out, $buffer);
}

fclose($in);
fclose($out);
unlink($file);
rename($tmpFile, $file);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for complementing my answer with an exemple for large files

Comment: How to preg_match for line containing "Diamond" and configure buffer to write string in the end of a line containing "Diamond" here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$string_Data = '444555';

$file_To_Edit = "./11.csv";

$opened_File = file($file_To_Edit) or die("Error. Code:2 - Can not open file $file_To_Edit"); // Reads entire file into array of file lines

$diamond_lines = preg_grep('#^Diamond#', $opened_File); // Finds array with line started with 'Diamonds'

foreach(array_keys($diamond_lines) as $key) { // Runs 'Diamonds' array

    $opened_File[$key] = substr($opened_File[$key], 0, -1) . $string_Data; // Removes the last character from 'Diamond' line (new line chracter) and adds $string_Data variable at the end

}

//var_dump($opened_File);

$f = fopen($file_To_Edit, 'w');

fwrite($f, implode("\n", $opened_File)); // Writes new .CSV file

fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: Why it outputs `array(18) { [0]=> string(13) "Categories, " [1]=> string(1) " " [2]=> string(1) " " [3]=> string(1) " " [4]=> string(1) " " [5]=> string(1) " " [6]=> string(1) " " [7]=> string(1) " " [8]=> string(1) " " [9]=> string(1) " " [10]=> string(1) " " [11]=> string(1) " " [12]=> string(1) " " [13]=> string(1) " " [14]=> string(1) " " [15]=> string(1) " " [16]=> string(30) "Diamond,10,11, 583583583583582" [17]=> string(11) "Coal,21,21," }` ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to comment `var_dump($opened_File);` - it dumps `$opened_File` variable. Modifyed my answer.